# Mockito: How do I mock an instance creation?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

consider that I need to mock the following line

```
employee.addOffer(employee, new Offer(details));
```

Now I need to mock the `new Offer(details)` to do nothing

The way I try is

```
doNothing().when(employee).addOffer(any(Employee.class), any(Offer.class));
```

This fails with `NullPointerException` because it tries to execute `new Offer(details)` and `details` is nothing

How can I mock `new Offer(details)` to return any other mock?

Comment: Have you read https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation ?  There may be something in there that will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mock `Offer`:

```
Offer mockOffer = mock(Offer.class);
employee.addOffer(employee, mockOffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to note that methods of Mockito mocks do nothing by default, so `doNothing` is redundant here.

Instead of answering directly to your question I'd like to point something about your test. It to mock value types, in this case `Employee`, generally speaking I would avoid to mock any value types being `Employee`, `Offer`, `Detail`, etc.

Instead, as your test seems to be about harnessing something about data, I would write a test where the value types are the fixture, and the outputed value types data will be verified.

If you shall need mocks you should focus on collaborators (in the sense of behavior).

---

For example imagine the following design (*it's pseudo-code*) :

```
class OfferProcessor {
    OfferClassifier classifie;
    Offer...
    ...

    process() { ... }
}

interface OfferClassifier {
    classify()
}

class EmployeeOfferCalssifier extends OfferClassifier {
    classify() { ... }
}
```

1. `OfferProcessor`, is obviously working with ***collaborators***, it the test you'd want to focus on the interactions between them. For example one test could focus on classification, mocking `OfferClassifier` and verifying that `classify` is called.
2. On the other hand `OfferClassifier` witch is an interface looks to be about manipulating data. So for `EmployeeOfferClassifier` I would focus my test on input and output data.

Of course reality might have much more complex granularity, but this test approach still applies. Also in the [article](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation) that @DavidWallace pointed out in the comment above, the same approach can be used if using the factory/provider pattern.